# Java Application SAP Commerce / Hybris shuts down without any reason

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud, application-shutdown

I have kind of weird problem and I can't find any reason or solution for it.

I have running a SAP Hybris Java Application, which uses an Tomcat for the frontend (don't know if that matters). There I started a cronjob to import stuff.

On my local maschine (macbook, 32 GB RAM) the cronjob runns about an hour and finish sucessfull. But on the server (ubuntu, 32 GB RAM) it takes 1 1/2 hours and the server shuts down with the reason:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | main    | 2021/03/12 15:26:13.032 | TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/03/12 15:26:13.433 | shutting down hybris registry..
```

With a bit of google I found this german page: https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/german/qna-shutdown.html#term 
It says that the unix system shut down the application. So I went to the syslog, but nothing tells me the reason for the shut down signal:

```
Mar 12 14:17:01 TESTBESRV01 CRON[18148]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 12 14:51:19 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 596 of user test.
Mar 12 15:17:01 TESTBESRV01 CRON[18411]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 12 15:24:30 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 598 of user test.
Mar 12 15:27:24 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 599 of user test.
Mar 12 15:27:25 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 600 of user test.
Mar 12 15:27:25 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 601 of user test.
Mar 12 15:27:28 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 602 of user test.
Mar 12 15:27:29 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 603 of user test.
Mar 12 15:27:35 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 604 of user test.
Mar 12 15:27:36 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 605 of user test.
Mar 12 15:28:09 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 606 of user test.
Mar 12 15:28:10 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 607 of user test.
Mar 12 15:28:12 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 608 of user test.
Mar 12 15:28:13 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 609 of user test.
Mar 12 15:28:19 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 610 of user test.
Mar 12 15:28:20 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 611 of user test.
Mar 12 15:28:53 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Session 612 of user test.
Mar 12 15:42:57 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Mar 12 15:42:58 TESTBESRV01 systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
```

Unfortunately I can't look back to see how much RAM was left, but I can show the full shut down log from the application: https://pastebin.com/ZQhXnYsu (too long for stackoverflow)

Comment: Does somebody else have access to your system? Can you maybe share your access log? AFAIK the application could be shutdown using a groovy script via admin console e.g.

Comment: Are you using the hourly crontab to run a job that takes more than an hour?

Comment: A few people have access, but now one was on that maschine to that time. The access log ends at 15:16:29, so it is way before the shutdown.

Comment: We have also a few jobs which take longer than one hour, but they are running at night. This job was started by myself to test it. There was now job, except solr sync running.

Comment: Looks like a SIGTERM signal.  so 'kill -15' or just 'kill'.  The shutdown log from hybris won't tell you anything other than: something else sent it a SIGTERM

Comment: @NeilHubert-Price but the system logs does not tell me anything too